# Type for File (list) metafield on Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am currently trying to get the backend to select multiple images for my custom metafield. But i cant find any information to tells me what the 'type' needs to be.

```
{
        "type": "Slideshow",
        "name": "Gallery",
        "settings": [
          {
            "id": "slide_image",
            "type": "image_picker",   
            "label": "Image"
          }
        ]
      }
```

[image: Backend]

[image: Metafield]

I want to be able to allow the user to select multiple images so I can connect my dynamic metafield.

Comment: meta-fields are associated with particular items, like collections, products, etc. can you let us know on which type you want to add to this above gallery?